# How can i stream input from a webcam over the internet using python?

Tags: python, sockets, udp, webcam

I've been searching the internet for hours trying to find a good way.

I can't use TCP because there can't be a significant delay in the stream. When i use UDP it displays a corrupted version of the image thanks to it being so unreliable. Not to mention there's a bunch of people telling me that UDP is not meant for transferring files and you shouldn't try and add onto UDP so as to avoid recreating TCP.

This is a small snippet of the code i was using server side for the UDP test.

```
def datagramReceived(self, datagram, address):
    while True:
        image = webcam.get_image()
        sio = StringIO(tostring(image, 'RGB'))

        while True:
            temp = sio.read(1024)
            if not temp: break
            self.transport.write(temp, address)
```

And a snippet of the *slightly* terrible client code:

```
def datagramReceived(self, datagram, host):
    if len(self.buff) != 921600:
        self.buff += datagram
    else:
        image = fromstring(self.buff, (640,480), 'RGB')
        screen.blit(image, (0,0))
        display.flip()
        self.buff = ''
```

Comment: You may consider the possibility to use some library like gstreamer or pyvlc. You could easily stream over RTMP. It will definitely work better than a custom protocol.

Comment: From what i can tell RTMP uses TCP which makes it too slow for streaming a webcam. Feel free to correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Ops, I meant [RTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol).

Comment: GStreamer with RTP seems pretty good, can you recommend a guide?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this question: [Python send and receive RTP packets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564817/python-send-and-receive-rtp-packets)
Also, Farstream has python bindings, you might want to check this out as well:
http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Farstream/